# C++ Multi-thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

In a Class, when I try to create a thread for a method like this:

```
void *RippleBrush::paintRippleOnce(void){
    while(1){
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j ++) {
            for(int i = 0; i < width; i ++){
                int point = j * height + i;
                data[point].a += ripple->rippleNow[point];
                ripple->CaculateNextRipple();
            }
        }
    }
}

void RippleBrush::paintRipple(){
    pthread_t ctrl_thread;
        if(pthread_create(&ctrl_thread, NULL, RippleBrush::paintRippleOnce, NULL) != 0){
            perror("pthread_create");
            exit(1);
        }
}
```

It show error: no matching function for call to 'pthread_create'.

How can I create a thread in one method for another method which is in the same class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <pthread.h>

int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr, 
                   void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

**Compile and link with `-pthread`.**

Comment: Thanks! but how to write a example of void *(*start_routin)(void *).  I know how to do it in main.cpp, but I fail to do it in other class.cpp.

Answer (score 0):

I think you had better make your real worker function as static:

```
void *RippleBrush::paintRippleOnce(void){
    while(1){
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j ++) {
            for(int i = 0; i < width; i ++){
                int point = j * height + i;
                data[point].a += ripple->rippleNow[point];
                ripple->CaculateNextRipple();
            }
        }
    }
}

void RippleBrush::paintRipple(){
    pthread_t ctrl_thread;
        if(pthread_create(&ctrl_thread,NULL, RippleBrush::paintRippleOnceWrapper,this)!=0){
            perror("pthread_create");
            exit(1);
        }
}

static void* RippleBrush::paintRippleOnceWrapper(void *args) {
   RippleBrush* brush= (RippleBrush*)args; // or dynamic_cast as you like
   brush->paintRippleOnce();
}
```